# Refresh ListView Android com SQL Server

Tags: android, listview

Estou fazendo uma aplicação onde nela tenho duas Activities: Uma que vai mostrar usuários que foram cadastrados em um `ListView`, e outra que vai possibilitar executar o CRUD.

Estou com uma dificuldade em como fazer um refresh sempre que eu fizer uma inserção, atualização ou a deleção de um dado na Activity 2 (a que faz o cadastro). Como devo proceder nesse caso?

Abaixo o código da classe FillList que faz o preenchimento no `ListView`:

```
    public class FillList extends AsyncTask <String,String,String> {
    String z="";

    List<Map<String, String>> prolist = new ArrayList<Map<String, String>>();

    @Override protected void onPreExecute()
    {
        progbar2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }

    @Override protected  void onPostExecute(String r){
        progbar2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        //Toast.makeText(MegaPermanentes_Usuarios.this, r, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        String[] from = {"A", "B"};
        int[] views = {R.id.lblproname, R.id.lblproend};
        final SimpleAdapter ADA = new SimpleAdapter(MegaPermanentes_Usuarios.this, prolist, R.layout.lsttemplate, from, views);
        listPro.setAdapter(ADA);

    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

        try{
            Connection con = connectionClass.connectionclass();
            if(con == null){
                z = "Conexão falhou";
            }else
                {
                String query = "select nome,endereco from usuarios";
                PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement(query);
                ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();

                while(rs.next()){
                    Map<String, String> datanum = new HashMap<String, String>();
                    datanum.put("A", rs.getString ("Nome"));
                    datanum.put("B", rs.getString("Endereco"));
                    prolist.add(datanum);
                }
            }
        }catch (Exception ex)
        {
            z = "Error Retrieving Data";
        }
        return z;
    }
}
```

A parte de inserção da outra Activity, segue abaixo:

```
    public class AddInfo extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>{


    Boolean isSucess = false;
    String infoName = editName.getText().toString();
    String infoDocu = editDocument.getText().toString();

    @Override
    protected  void onPreExecute()
    {
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        String z = "";
        if(infoName.trim().equals("") || infoDocu.trim().equals(""))
        {
            Toast.makeText(MegaPermanentes.this, "Por favor digite um nome e um documento", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        }
        else{
            try{
                Connection con = connectionClass.connectionclass();
                if (con == null){
                    Toast.makeText(MegaPermanentes.this, "Verifique sua conexão", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                }
                else
                {
                    String query = "insert into usuarios (nome,endereco) values ('" + infoName + "','" +infoDocu + "')";
                    PreparedStatement preparedStatement = con.prepareStatement(query);
                    preparedStatement.executeUpdate();
                    z = "Cadastro inserido com sucesso";
                }
            }catch( Exception ex){
                Toast.makeText(MegaPermanentes.this, "ex" , Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            }
        }

        return z;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result)
    {

        progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        Toast.makeText(MegaPermanentes.this, result, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);

    }

}
```

Comment: É um banco externo (sqlite) ou interno? Cadê a parte que você faz a inserção?! ou exclusão?

Comment: @white. É um banco externo (Sql Server), editarei o post com a classe de inserção.

Comment: Poderia fazer o carregamento da lista no onResume da primeira activity.

Comment: @AndréOzawa então eu crio um método onResume e coloco a parte de preencher a lista?

Comment: Sim. Na verdade vai sobreescrever `protected void onResume() {` . É uma forma rápida de implementar. Se preferir não recarregar a lista, pode devolver o objeto alterado, e aí faz a manipulação da lista.

Comment: Poderia me mostrar como ficaria o código? Ainda não entendi o que disse, desculpe-me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`onResume` é executado após `onStart`, que pode vir após de `onCreate` ou `onRestart`, depende do estado da atividade. Recomendo uma olhada em [ciclo de vida da activity](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle.html).
Seria algo como:

```
public class PrimeiraActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    //... code

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        // carregar lista. Ex.: fillListAsyncTask.execute();
    }
}
```

Considerando que ao fazer inserção, atualização ou a deleção de um dado na Activity 2, ela esteja sendo finalizada.

Comment: Então esse método irá sempre executar quando eu voltar pra Activity? (Já tinha visto uma parte do Ciclo de uma activity.) Me perdoe, ainda estou aprendendo sobre Android e Java.

Comment: Muito obrigado André, deu certo aqui! Estava com outra lógica na cabeça, mas esta foi mais prática ;)

Comment: Sim, sempre irá executar. Tranquilo, o importante é sempre estarmos aprendendo. Boa @MatheusArduino, espero ter ajudado, se ajudou poderia setar como resposta? Pode ser útil a outros também.